# Converting a string to LineString

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a string read from a csv file:

`'LINESTRING (-79.494722 43.777724, -79.494805 43.777636, -79.49503799999999 43.777581, -79.495277 43.777524)'`

I want to convert this string object to
`shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString` object.

Thousands of lines are in that csv file. Is there a way to convert them?

Comment: Does csv file contain only `LINESTRING` strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this script.

```
from shapely.wkt import loads

# open file and read lines
with open('path/to/file.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines = [loads(l) for l in file.readlines()]
    
    
print(lines)

# [<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object ...>,
#  <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object ...>,
#  ...]
```

If the string is between single quotes, change `lines = ...`  as:

```
lines = [loads(l.replace('\'', '')) for l in file.readlines()]
```